# iPhone SDK: Profile was not copied because it cannot be played on this iPod

Tags: iphone, provisioning, adhoc

I've created an AdHoc distribution profile. When I try to copy it to an 3g iPod touch, I get the following error message.

Profile.mobileprovision was not copied to the iPod because it cannot be played in this iPod.

I am confused.

Why would I have a problem installing a Adhoc provisioning profile on an iPod touch?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't registered that specific device in the Provisioning Portal.

For each and every device, you have to make sure they are added to your iPhone Provisioning Portal, just like you did with your original device using the UDID.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the sdk installed in Xcode that is on your iPod. That caught me out earlier this week - upgraded my iPad to 3.2.1 and Xcode could only handle 3.2, so had to then upgrade that too